# Webdriver&Python: Iterating through the list and adding a new element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I have a problem with my test - adding a new query on a site. There are 2 existing queries already with id-0, id-1... You don't know how many queries will be added so I want to add a new query without giving the specific id number. I was trying to start with iterating but I don't know how to proceed with this code...

```
list_of_elements = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("cssselector")
    for element in list_of_elements:
        wd.find_element_by_link_text("Add test").click()
        queries = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*="id_query-1-title"]')
        index = str(len(queries))
        wd.find_element_by_id('id_query-' + index + '-title').click()
        wd.find_element_by_id('id_query-' + index + '-title').clear()
        wd.find_element_by_id('id_query-' + index + '-title').send_keys("ABC")
```

Comment: So what is your problem/question?

Comment: I get a new query with id_query-2-title but what should i do to get a new query if there are more than exisitng 2 queries? I get/modify always a query with id_query-2-title...

Comment: Can you share `URL` of target page or at least `HTML`?

Comment: you are iterating over a list of elements, and then doing nothing with those elements.  why?

Comment: Andersson: Unfortunately I can't :(

Comment: @Corey Goldberg: I think I'm stuck. I was thinking about returning element += 1

Comment: @Storm I'm not sure what that means.  `element` is an instance of `WebElement`...  you can't add an integer to it... that makes no sense

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg: maybe I should change the name from element to i: for i in list_of_elements:

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg: And then I would like to return i += 1

Comment: @Storm, renaming element won't help... it's NOT an index

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg: hmmm, you right...

Comment: @Storm, and what is `len(queries)`? Are you sure that it's more than `1`? Maybe you need to use `wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*="id_query-"]')`? However, without `HTML` it's hard to understand what you actually intend to do...

Comment: @Andersson: Understand, thx for your help :) I just want to check want is the last query (last item on my page) and add the new one... I thought that I should look at it as the list

Comment: Please do add the HTML code snippet @Storm. It will be easier to comprehend what you are getting at and help you out. :)

Comment: Thank you @Subh, I've already found a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have a solution. Thank you for your help!

```
test = wd.find_elements_by_class_name('classname')
    test_count = len(test)
    test_string = str(test_count - 1)
    wd.find_element_by_id('id_query-' + test_string + '-title').click()
    wd.find_element_by_id('id_query-' + test_string + '-title').send_keys("ABC")
```